# pthread_mutex_lock blocks but __lock = 0

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, mutex

I am writing a multi-threaded program, and running into deadlock.

one of threads blocks while other threads are sleeping (cond_wait)

so i entered ctrl+c to go into gdb terminal

```
(gdb) info thread
  5 Thread 0x1c6ff4a0 (LWP 723)  __pthread_cond_wait (cond=0x420c50, mutex=0x420c34)
at pthread_cond_wait.c:156
  3 Thread 0x1bcf34a0 (LWP 721)  __pthread_cond_wait (cond=0x41a530, mutex=0x41a514)
at pthread_cond_wait.c:156
* 1 Thread 0x1b2c9720 (LWP 716)  __lll_lock_wait (futex=0x1be08240, private=0)
at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/lowlevellock.c:46
(gdb) bt
#0  __lll_lock_wait (futex=0x1be08240, private=0)
at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/lowlevellock.c:46
#1  0x1afa1540 in __pthread_mutex_lock (mutex=0x1be08240) at pthread_mutex_lock.c:61
#2  0x1abb7984 in readerWait (FrameInfo=0x1be08240, sem=0x1aad4000)
at CamIPCSource.cpp:282
......
```

i can see that this thread is blocked at CamIPCSource.cpp:282

but when i change into frame #2 and print the mutex

```
(gdb) frame 2
#2  0x1abb7984 in readerWait (FrameInfo=0x1be08240, sem=0x1aad4000)
at CamIPCSource.cpp:282
(gdb) p FrameInfo->m_Reader
$1 = {__data = {__lock = 0, __count = 0, __owner = 0, __kind = 0, __nusers = 0, {
  __spins = 0, __list = {__next = 0x0}}}, __size = '\000' <repeats 23 times>,
__align = 0}
```

Isn't that weird?  block on a nonblock mutex?

and when i let the gdb continue, the program successfully get the lock

### **my question**: what else can i do to know the reason why the thread block at a non-block mutex?

environment: compiled by mipsel-linux-gnu-g++-4.4, running on mips (libpthread-2.11.3)

here is the code snippet(CamIPCSource.cpp) where the thread blocks:

```
277 int readerWait(frame_info_t* FrameInfo, sem_t* sem) {
278     int ret;
279
280     if (FrameInfo == NULL || sem == NULL)   return -1;
281
282     pthread_mutex_lock(&FrameInfo->m_Reader);
283     /*while ((ret = pthread_mutex_trylock(&FrameInfo->m_Reader)) != 0) {
284         if (ret == EBUSY)
285             fprintf(stderr, "-");
286         else {
287             _err("pthread_mutex_trylock:(%s)\n", strerror(ret));
288             return -1;
289         }                                                                                              
290     }*/
291                                                                                            292     FrameInfo->ReaderCount++;
293     if (FrameInfo->ReaderCount == 1) {
294         if (sem_wait(sem) != 0) {
295             _err("sem_wait:(%s)\n", strerror(errno));
296             FrameInfo->ReaderCount--;
297             if ((ret = pthread_mutex_unlock(&FrameInfo->m_Reader)) != 0);
298                 _err("pthread_mutex_unlock:(%s)\n", strerror(ret));
299             return -1;
300         }
301      }
302     if ((ret = pthread_mutex_unlock(&FrameInfo->m_Reader)) != 0)
303         _err("pthread_mutex_unlock:(%s)\n", strerror(ret));
304
305     return 0;
306 }
```

btw, i've tried to replace pthread_mutex_lock with pthread_mutex_trylock at line 283~290

and it works quite well with some "-" output occasionally :(

Here is ReaderSignal function (ReaderWait/ReaderSignal are the only two function which access this mutex)

```
339 int readerSignal(frame_info_t* FrameInfo, sem_t* sem) {
340     int ret;
341
342     if (FrameInfo == NULL || sem == NULL)   return -1; 
343
344     pthread_mutex_lock(&FrameInfo->m_Reader);
345     /*while ((ret = pthread_mutex_trylock(&FrameInfo->m_Reader)) != 0) {
346         if (ret == EBUSY)
347             fprintf(stderr, "-");
348         else {
349             _err("pthread_mutex_trylock:(%s)\n", strerror(ret));
350             return -1;
351         }
352     }*/
353     FrameInfo->ReaderCount--;
354     if (FrameInfo->ReaderCount == 0) {
355         if (sem_post(sem) != 0) {
356             _err("sem_post:(%s)\n", strerror(errno));
357             FrameInfo->ReaderCount++;
358             if ((ret = pthread_mutex_unlock(&FrameInfo->m_Reader)) != 0)
359                 _err("pthread_mutex_unlock:(%s)\n", strerror(ret));
360             return -1;
361         }
362
363     }
364     if ((ret = pthread_mutex_unlock(&FrameInfo->m_Reader)) != 0)
365         _err("pthread_mutex_unlock:(%s)\n", strerror(ret));
366
367     return 0;
368 }
```

Comment: Maybe if you add the source code it'll help see your problem

Comment: Are those the only two case where this specific mutex in used? Also `pthread_mutex_lock()` misses error checking! How is this mutex initialised?

Comment: There's another function called readerSignal which is opposite to readerWait in the post. Two functions both start with a pthread_mutex_lock and end with pthread_unlock. I initialized the mutex by pthread_mutex_init with PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED attribute. Actually, what i want to know is there any way (except gdb print) to examine the status of mutex

Answer (score 1):

Debugging multithreaded programs with GDB is typically difficult.  Better to use a tool that is designed to handle multithreaded issues.  I highly recommend looking at Helgrind:

http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/hg-manual.html

From that page: "Helgrind is a Valgrind tool for detecting synchronisation errors in C, C++ and Fortran programs that use the POSIX pthreads threading primitives."

It will supply information on potential race conditions, deadlock, etc.  Pretty awesome really.  It has saved me more than once.

Good luck!